# TS keyof typeof <Object> does not allow object.keys(<Object>) to be assigned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeof, keyof

I do not understand what the problem is with this code.

Here is my code:

```
export type SportsTypes = keyof typeof SportsIcons

export const sports: SportsTypes[] = Object.keys(SportsIcons);
```

I am typing my variable to the keys of an object.
But, when I then try to assign an array of said keys to this variable, I get the ts error:
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("Football" | "GameController" | "Tennis" | "Basketball" | "PingPong" | "Volleyball" | "HockeyPuck" | "Chess" | "AmericanFootball" | "Baseball" | "SandVolleyball")[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export type SportsTypes = keyof typeof SportsIcons

export const sports = Object.keys(SportsIcons) as SportsTypes[];
```

Comment: awesome this did the trick. I even knew about this rule and use it elsewhere in this app, not sure why it escaped me here.

Thank you!

Comment: That is not a solution but a hack. Nothing prevents from putting any other object and make that assertion incorrect without any error.